# Como calculo dos minimos?

Tags: javascript, python

Realizar un programa que lea 1000 números enteros desde teclado. Informar en pantalla cuáles son
los **dos números mínimos** leídos.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). ¿Qué has intentado hacer hasta el momento? Lectura recomendada [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2874#2874)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

los agrupas en una lista y despues a esa lista le aplicas la funcion sort() para ordenar los numeros de esta manera:

```
Lista = lista.sort()
```

y despues pides que te devuelva el indice 0 y 1 obteniendo asi los 2 mas pequeños:

```
return Lista[0],Lista[1]
```

o

```
print(Lista[0],Lista[1])
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Cuando las preguntas no cumplen con los lineamientos es mejor no responderlas ya que incitan a usuarios a únicamente solicitar ayuda sin hacer ningún esfuerzo y ese no es el propósito del sitio. Saludos